# Inherited member function accessing data members

Tags: c++, inheritance, member-functions, datamember

Consider the sample code below:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
    private:
        static int a;
        int b;

    protected:

    public:

        A() : b(0) {}

        void modify()
        {
            a++;
            b++;
        }

        void display()
        {
            cout << a <<"\n";
            cout << b <<"\n";
        }

};

int A::a=0;

class B : public A {

    private:
        int b;

    public:
        B(): b(5)
        {
        }

};

int main()
{
    A ob1;
    B ob2;
    ob1.display();
    ob2.display();

    return 0;

}
```

In the code above, the `class A` has a private data member `b`and `class B` also has a private data member `b`. The function `display()` is used to display the data members.
When i invoke display() using `ob1.display()`, display() accesses the private data member `b` of class A. I understand that. But when i invoke display using `ob2.display`, which `b` does display() access? Is it the `b` of class A or `b` of class B? Kindly explain the why it accesses `class A's b` or `class B's b`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will access `A::b`. The `display` method implementation in class `A` has no clue about the existence of `B::b` at all, let alone using it.  For all intents and purposes, `B::b` is separate from `A::b`.  Only in the scope of `B` itself, the name conflict makes `b` refer to `B::b`, hiding `A::b`.  Member variables cannot be `virtual`.

Comment: Thanks : So what is the use of `class B` inheriting `class A's` `display()` function. `class B` has inherited the function `display()` from `class A` and so i expected `display()` to access `class B's b`

Comment: @LinuxPenseur There are a lot of uses. This is simply not one of them. To achieve what you want, you could either not introduce a new variable and initialize the base class `b` via a base constructor call, or introduce a `virtual` method in base class, which returns the value of `b` in base class and override it to return the value of `b` in the derived class.

Comment: Or simply have a method in derived class which accesses derived class members and propogates the call further by calling base class method which accesses the base class members.

Answer (score 2):

`ob2.display()` will access the derived class member.
The member function call is always evaluated on `this`, `this->display()` the `this` in case points to object of your Base class and hence any reference to `b` inside the `display()` function is evaluated as `this->b` which is `b` of the Base class.

This is because `display()` of the Base class has no knowledge of whether any other class derives from it. Base class is always independent of the Derived class. To solve a problem the uual pattern followed is to provide a `display()` method in the Derived class which then in turn calls the `dsiplay()` method of the Base class.

```
void B::display()
{
    //cout << a <<"\n";
    cout << b <<"\n";
    A::display();    
}
```

Comment: Please note that display function is in class A, in case you have missed it. Could you rephrase your answer based on it. I say this because ob2.display does not seem to access the derived class member.

Comment: Now i have the doubt:). why is `this` pointer in the case of `ob2.display()` pointing to object of Base class? ob2 is the object of the derived class.

Comment: @LinuxPenseur: Becasue `display()` is member of the Base class.The call to `display()` is resolved in the scope of Base class `A`.The base class knows nothing about any other classes that may derive from it,if you think of it, it makes sense that there is no such reverse dependency.The `b` in derived class will only be referred when in the scope of the derived class.

Answer (score 0):

It is class `A`. `A::display()` cannot access B private members.

Comment: Answered this part of question - "But when i invoke display using ob2.display, which b does display() access?"